# MySQL Order By: conditional multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a list that is ordered by the date of entry:

- JOB C, en-GB, 2016-01-12 08:00:00
- JOB B, en-GB, 2016-01-12 08:10:00
- JOB A, en-GB, 2016-01-12 08:20:00

Let's say that I now add:

- JOB B, fr-FR, 2016-01-12 08:30:00

In the current query, the list would look like this:

- JOB C, en-GB, 2016-01-12 08:00:00
- JOB B, en-GB, 2016-01-12 08:10:00
- JOB A, en-GB, 2016-01-12 08:20:00
- JOB B, fr-FR, 2016-01-12 08:30:00

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d61d7/2

I need the result to look like this:

- JOB C, en-GB, 2016-01-12 08:00:00
- JOB B, en-GB, 2016-01-12 08:10:00
- JOB B, fr-FR, 2016-01-12 08:30:00
- JOB A, en-GB, 2016-01-12 08:20:00

So the initial sorting is by created_at, but JOB B, fr-FR is now below the JOB B, en-GB record.

Sorry for the convoluted explanation...

Comment: in this case, "Job B" and "fr-FR" already inserted in your table?

Comment: yes, manually, to demonstrate the desired outcome. The SQLFiddle should show the entry, but in the incorrect place. I need it to match the demo above...

Answer (score 1):

if it's the case, i would prefer using a UNION ALL and add "id" to the select statement.
here's the code

```
SELECT *
FROM (
select 1 as id, name, job, created_at from yourtable where created_at <= '2016-01-12 08:10:00'
union all
select 2 as id, name, job, created_at from yourtable where job = 'fr-FR'
union all
select 3 as id, name, job, created_at from yourtable where created_at = '2016-01-12 08:20:00'
) x
order by x.id, x.created_at
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think I'd need a more workable solution. I have updated the original post, to maybe explain the issue.